# Combinatorial interpretation of a sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

I would like to know if there exists a way to interpret this sum by a combinatorial argument
$$\sum _ { k = 0 } ^ { n } \frac { ( - 4 ) ^ { k } k ! } { ( 2 k + 1 ) ! ( n - k ) ! } = \frac { 1 } { ( 2 n + 1 ) \cdot n ! }$$
As of now I have tried coming up with some inclusion exclusion argument by multiplying the sum on the LHS by $(2n+1)n!$ but have failed in doing so.

Would appreciate any guidance or help  towards a solution

Edit: I found this identity from this mathematical reflections paper I came across
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q_TdS1btxtMd-wkanMPGSHeXg3Wq2y-P/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 2):

Inclusion-exclusion will need $(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}$, so also multiply the summand by $k!/k!$ to rewrite as
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k} \frac{(2n+1)4^k}{(2k+1)\binom{2k}{k}}=1.$$

Comment: Hello,thanks for the hint but I still am unable to find a setup that counts for the expression obtained would you mind in helping out a bit more

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion as I'm familiar with it also need integer summands, which isn't the case here.

Comment: I don't have it worked out.  I was just rewriting in a more suitable form for inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @arctictern Inclusion-exclusion also applies to probabilities, and the summands need not be integer.